# i get Null.pointer.exception when i try to identify element in the current class using driver instance from another class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

In below LogOutfunc class,
 I have created object for the class LoginPage and when I run LogOutfunc class program, Launch() method is passed. However, the 
LogOut() method fails with java.lang.NullPointerException.

After login(), the url navigates to a page which contains the objects present in the LogOut() method but it doesn't identify the object.Suggest me a solution of how to use the driver instance in the current class.

**1. LogOutfunc Class**

```
package TestNG;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LogOutfunc {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test()
    public void Launch() throws NoAlertPresentException, InterruptedException {
        LoginPage tc1 = new LoginPage();
        tc1.setUp();
        tc1.Login("test_Sharmila","Welcome123","Sharmila");
    }

    @Test()
        public void LogOut() {
        System.out.println("Logout Functionality");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id=\"usrmenu\"]]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='logoutx']//a[text()='Logout']")).click();
        System.out.println("Logged out from the page");
```

---

**2. LoginPage class**

```
package TestNG;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginPage {

    String driverPath = "C:\\Selenium\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe";
    public WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl = "https://www.myguruavatar.com/demo";
    String expectedtUrl = "https://www.myguruavatar.com/demo/index.php?option=com_avatarprofile&view=avatarprofileform";

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void Login(String userName, String password, String Name)
            throws NoAlertPresentException, InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"modlgn-username\"]")).sendKeys(userName);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"modlgn-passwd\"]")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/fieldset/div/p[2]/input")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"hmelogin\"]")).click();

        if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(expectedtUrl)) {
            System.out.println("Login Success");



        } else {
            System.out.println("Login Failure");
```

please let me know how to use the driver instance in the current class.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please make the title more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Its because driver is null. See here

```
public class LogOutfunc {

public WebDriver driver;
```

You are driver is null in this class. Launch method will work as there is valid driver in that class.

So you need to change the way of implementation.

simple way is LogOutfunc  extends LoginPage and delete this line public WebDriver driver; in LogoutFun class.